# Is there a pointer-to-member equivalent in Java?

Tags: java

I have a class which holds some colors for a GUI, which the program can change to its liking. For a specific element of the GUI, I'd like to be able to specify a color which is a member of that class. In C++, I could use something like

```
int Pallete::*color = &Pallete::highlight;
Pallete pallete; // made in or passed to the constructor
// ...
void draw() {
    drawing.color(pallete.*color);
    // ...
}
```

Is there an equivalent in java? I've thought about using `getField(String)` in the Class class, or keeping the colors in a Map with string keys, but neither of these seem like very good solutions, because they rely on strings, and the compiler can't enforce that they are actually members of Pallete. I could also put all of the color names in an enum, and have some getter function which returns the associated color, but that seems like more work for me.

Comment: Tom, you nail it, either strings (and java.lang.reflect.Field) and not-so-good tool-chain support or ugly enums :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just use the `Integer` class. Since its a class, it obeys reference semantics.

This would give you a class like

```
class Palette
{
    public static Integer highlight; // this gets initialize to whatever value

    public Integer color = highlight;

}
```

#### Edit

Okay, so the `Integer` class describes an immutable type, so you cannot change the value held by an `Integer`. The solution is pretty simple, though. You can just define your own, *mutable* class, like so:

```
class MyInteger {

    private int value;

    public MyInteger(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return i;
    }

    public void setValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Of course, this example only provides the most basic functionality. You could always add more if you feel like it. You may also find it useful to use an internal `Integer` rather than an `int`, or perhaps also to extend the `Number` class (as the `Integer` class does).

If you declare `highlight` and `color` to be of `MyInteger` type, and assign `highlight` to `color`, then changes to `highlight` *will* be reflected in `color`:

```
Palette.highlight.setValue(0);
palette.color = Palette.highlight;
Palette.highlight.setValue(1);
System.out.println(palette.color); // This line will now print "1" instead of "2"
```

One potential drawback of this method is that you cannot write an assignment like

```
Palette.highlight = 0;
```

Instead you must use `setValue()` to change the value of an instance of `MyInteger`. However, I don't think this is a great loss, since it achieves the functionality you requested.

Comment: Is there a way to set the value of an Integer besides `highlight = new Integer(something);`? The reason I'd like to keep a reference is that the value of highlight might change, but if I just assign a new Integer to it, `color` would no longer reference the same Integer object, and would still have to old value.

Comment: Ah, I see what you want now. Unfortunately, in Java `Integer` is an immutable type, so there is no way to achieve what you are looking for with `Integer`. However, I will add to my answer to show you how you *can* achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a direct equivalent, no.  You could however just declare a method

```
public class Pallette {
    public Color color() {
       return Pallette.highlight;
    }
}
```

Or obviously you could just inline uses of `highlight`.

If `highlight` isn't going to change however, there's nothing stopping you from assigning it to a parallel constant:

```
 public static final Color color = Pallette.highlight;
```

Comment: There is actually a direct equivalent, bit it is very obtuse, inconvenient, and difficult to use:  [sun.misc.Unsafe](http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/sun/misc/Unsafe.html)

Comment: @aroth: Yeah and if you use JNI you can even get the perfect equivalent ;) Unsafe has its name (and package) for a good reason. No good reason to get a beginner (or pretty much anyone else) to use it.

Comment: @Aroth, java.lang.reflect.Field does the same actually

Answer (score 0):

I may be missing something, but this seems like a perfect application for Java enums.

```
public enum Pallete
{
    highlight, normal, redact
};
```

---

```
Pallete color = Pallete.highlight;
void draw() {
    drawing.color(color);
}
```

You may want my "Pallete" to be a member of your Pallete class, not a standalone enum - works either way.

Enum's are very much more powerful than this.  You can add functions, say, to provide the RGB values of the colors as well.